# Scrolling issues with section auto height (fullpage)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I have some problems with my data-menuanchor's on smaller screens. When i'm on desktop view my anchors works just fine, but when i shrink my window size and go over to `responsiveWidth` my links start messing up. For example when i click on 4 the window goes to 4, then i click 2 and the window goes to 2 but when i click 3 from there it keeps scrolling up until about half my first page. But if i for example click on last page in my navication bar and then on 3 it goes to page 3. It kinda depends on witch order i click on each button how well it works.

A while ago i didn't have this problem but then i made some changes and now i cant remember what that was. My guess is that it has something to do with positions of elements but i'm not sure. I know it might be hard to pinpoint down exactly what is wrong but i would appreciate any tips on what could be the problem here or how to find it.

**Edit:** After further investigation it seems that as my pages doesn't cover the entire window (as it should) because of `section fp-auto-height` and `mycontainer` the anchor either shows the pages at the bottom of the window or at the top. so when i scroll from bottom to top my pages/sections anchor at top of the screen but they can still anchor at the bottom of my screen. So the problem might be that i cant get the pages to always scroll to the top of my sections instead of somewhere in between.

**Edit 2** Some pictures to maybe make it clearer.

**how it should be:**
[image]

**How it is:**
[image]

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-container">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-container">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage" title="knapp" id="logo">asdasd</a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="secondPage" id="2"><a href="#secondPage">2/a></li>
        <li data-menuanchor="thirdPage" id="3"><a href="#thirdPage">3</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="4thpage" id="4"><a href="#4thpage">4</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="5thpage" id="5"><a href="#5thpage">5</a></li>
            <li data-menuanchor="lastPage" id="5"><a href="#lastPage">5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section" data-menuanchor="firstPage">
        <div id="main" class="mainfront">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="midmain">
                    <div class="col-sm-5"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h1>Kqweqweqwe</h1>
                        <p>qwe qwe qwe qweqw eqwe qwe qwe qwe qwe qwe qwe qwe qweqw eqwe qw eqw eqw eqwwe</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section fp-auto-height" data-menuanchor="secondPage">
        <div id="main" class="mainfilo">
            <div class="mycontainer">
                <div id="myheader"></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="head-text">   
                            <h3>2</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="mid-text" class="dark-text">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-push-6">
                            <p>w qweqwe qwe qeq we qweqw eqw qwe qwe qwe qweq weq</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-3">
                            <div id="bild" class="bildfilo"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Make sure you use the latest version of fullpage.js 2.7.8

Comment: yea iv'e tried that. but since i didn't have this problem before i don't think it has anything to do with the different version of things. it only seem to occur when i scroll from top to bottom, the other way around works just fine. it seems as if the positions of my anchors gets messed up around page 2 and 3. Almost as if the top of each section are stretched out further than the size of `mycontainer`

Comment: Provide a reproduction online in jsfiddle or codepen.